# reactjs state changed but ui component not updated

Tags: reactjs

When handling input event, updated the state but ui component not refreshed.

my versions is below

**node --version**

v12.6.0

**npm --version**

6.11.3

**"package.json"**

"react": "^16.9.0",

**here is my codes**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      aviableDymOptions: [],
      selectedDymOptions: [],
      displayDymOptions: [],
      controllerValues: {}
    };

    this.dymInputChangeHandler = this.dymInputChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.dymChangeHandler = this.dymChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.resetDymOptions = this.resetDymOptions.bind(this);
```

```
  componentDidMount() {

    let controllerValues = {};
    // default value
    this.props.dymOptions.map((item) => {

      controllerValues[item.id + RB_CB] = true;
      controllerValues[item.id + RB_DDCMP] = '';
      controllerValues[item.id + RB_IN] = '';
    });
    // update state
    this.setState({
      aviableDymOptions: this.props.dymOptions,
      controllerValues: controllerValues
    });
  }
```

```
  dymChangeHandler(e) {
    if (isEmpty(e) || isEmpty(e.value)) {

      return;
    }

    let selectedOption = e.value;
    let selectedControllType = selectedOption.controllType;
    if (isEmpty(selectedControllType)) {

      return;
    }

    let displayDymOptions = this.state.displayDymOptions.slice();
    let aviableDymOptions = this.state.aviableDymOptions.slice();
    let selectedDymOptions = this.state.selectedDymOptions.slice();

    let checkboxId = selectedOption.id + RB_CB;
    let compartorId = selectedOption.id + RB_DDCMP;
    let inputId = selectedOption.id + RB_IN;

    if (selectedControllType === global.dmyControllType.TEXT) {
      // [OK] create componenets with default value in componentDidMount
      // checkbox / dorpdown / inputtext
      displayDymOptions.push(
        <div id={selectedOption.id + 'DivGrid'} key={selectedOption.id} className="p-grid">
          <div id={selectedOption.id + 'DivLabel'} className={this.props.cnDymItemLabel}>
            <RbCheckBox id={checkboxId}
              value={this.state.controllerValues[checkboxId]}
              onChange={this.dymInputChangeHandler}
              checked={true}
            />
            <label id={selectedOption.id + 'Label'} htmlFor={checkboxId} className="p-checkbox-label">
              {selectedOption.label}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div id={selectedOption.id + 'DivOperator'} className={this.props.cnDymItemOperator}>
            <DropdownLocalDataExt
              id={compartorId}
              value={this.state.controllerValues[compartorId]}
              options={COMPARATOR_TXT}
              onChange={this.dymInputChangeHandler}
              showClear={true}
            />
          </div>
          <div id={selectedOption.id + 'DivContent'} className={this.props.cnDymItemContent}>
            <RbInputText id={inputId}
              value={this.state.controllerValues[inputId]}
              onChange={(e) => this.dymInputChangeHandler(e)} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    // remove selected items from dropdown
    aviableDymOptions.map((item, idx) => {

      if (item.id === selectedOption.id) {

        selectedDymOptions.push(item);
        aviableDymOptions.splice(idx, 1);

        return;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      displayDymOptions: displayDymOptions,
      aviableDymOptions: aviableDymOptions,
      selectedDymOptions: selectedDymOptions,

    });
  };
```

```
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="p-grid">
          <div className="p-col-12 p-md-12 p-lg-12 btn-div dym-query">
            <span className="p-float-label-dropdown">
              <DropdownLocalDataExt
                id={this.props.id}
                value={null}
                options={this.state.aviableDymOptions}
                onChange={this.dymChangeHandler}
                optionLabel="label"
              />
              <label htmlFor={this.props.id} className="float-label">
                {i18n.get('label.dynamic.query')}
              </label>
            </span>
            <BtnReset
              permissionoff={true}
              handleClick={this.resetDymOptions}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        {this.state.displayDymOptions}
      </>
    );
  }
```

[NG] When typing , the inputtext element is not updated with this.state.displayDymOptions.xxxIptx
any idea to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure you need `e.target.value`. Not just `e.value`.

Comment: what is dymInputChangeHandler() method!

Comment: state in dymChangeHandler does not change

Comment: You can use console.log to see what works and what doesn't maybe put some in dymChangeHandler to see if it reaches setState and if not, where it breaks.

Comment: please add codepen or codesandbox link for people to help you